# Mozilla form.submit() not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mozilla

I am creating a dynamic form  using following code,

```
function createForm() {
    var f = document.createElement("form");

    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('action',"./Upload");
    f.setAttribute('name',"initiateForm");
    f.acceptCharset="UTF-8";

    var name = document.createElement("input");
    name.setAttribute('type',"text");
    name.setAttribute('name',"projectname");
    name.setAttribute('value',"saket");

    f.appendChild(name);

    f.submit();

}
```

But in Mozilla nothing happens but code works as expected ( in chrome).
This code is being called by another function which is invoked by button on click event.
After executing this code i am returning false.

Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Maybe because you didn't append your form to the DOM? try to add `document.body.appendChild( f );` before submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the new created form to the document, because it was not there on page load.

Try this:

```
function createForm() {
    var f = document.createElement("form");

    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('action',"./Upload");
    f.setAttribute('name',"initiateForm");
    f.acceptCharset="UTF-8";

    var name = document.createElement("input");
    name.setAttribute('type',"text");
    name.setAttribute('name',"projectname");
    name.setAttribute('value',"saket");

    f.appendChild(name);
    document.body.appendChild(f); // added this
    f.submit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar error just resolved the same.
If you have just used `<form></form>` tag and trying to submit then it gives error in older version of mozill while it works in newer version and other browsers.
The form tag should be under `<html><body>` tag. e.g. `<html><body><form></form></body></html>`