# form.submit() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using following javascript function to construct a form and submitting it to the server. It works fine in Chrome browser but not working in Firefox.

```
function loadPage(url, projectName){
    var jForm = $('<form></form>');
    jForm.attr('action', url);
    jForm.attr('method', 'post');

    var jInput = $("<input>");
    jInput.attr('name', 'curPrj');
    jInput.attr('value', projectName);
    jForm.append(jInput);

    jForm.submit();
}
```

I got some suggestion from SE's older post [Mozilla form.submit() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968565/mozilla-form-submit-not-working), to append the form to document body `document.body.appendChild(jForm)` but unfortunately that didn't work for me either. I got following error in debug console when I used `document.body.appendChild(jForm)` before form submit.

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node. @ http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/global.js
```

Am I missing something here? Pls advise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`document.body.appendChild(jForm)` won't work because `jForm` is not a dom element, it is a jQuery object so add the below script before `jForm.submit();`

```
jForm.appendTo('body')
```

---

```
function loadPage(url, projectName) {
    var jForm = $('<form></form>', {
        action: url,
        method: 'post'
    });

    $("<input>", {
        name: 'curPrj',
        value: projectName
    }).appendTo(jForm);

    jForm.appendTo('body').submit();
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, it worked now. Thanks a lot Arun. :) And thanks for the enhanced version of the code.